# Edit smart object

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

One of my client gave me a mock up for his new website. He needs to change a small text appears under the logo. When I checked the psd file, logo couldn't edit because it shows as a smart object. I double click it and open with illustrator. Then expand the layer. But I couldn't edit there also. It shows this letters one by one. How can I edit this?

**Need to edit this texts.**

[image: Need to edit this texts.]

**View in Illustrator.**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The type has been converted to outlines. It is not editable live type. It is essentially art, not type.

You'll have to retype whatever it is you want to add and delete the existing shapes (letters).

Comment: Got it :) Any great way to find a font family?

Comment: well there's http://whatthefont.com

Comment: The client also can still be there. Ask!